# Bulk renaming files where some text in the name

Tags: php

I've made a mistake in bulk renaming files in one folder on a live server. Basically I've lost the extension for tons of `.jpeg` files. Now they look like `file1jpeg`,`file2jpeg`, etc.

How can I scan the entire folder and replace the file names ending in "jpeg" with ".jpeg", like `file1.jpeg` ?

LE. Some files might already have dots (".") in the name.

Many thanks!

Comment: Well, you create a script that reads the directory listing and decides for each file to rename it or not. What is the issue in that?

Comment: The issue is that now the "jpeg" files have no extension (they're missing the dot ... ".jpeg"). I need an advice to add a dot (".") in the file names before "jpeg" ending.

Comment: Sure, that is what you made clear in your question. And I gave to answer how to do that.

Comment: You should show some effort so far...Don't expect that somebody will write the whole script for you... ;) That's how SO works.

Comment: I'm struggling here, I have almost no experience with regex, which would be the best solution.

Comment: @valicu2000 try my below answer I faced some issue and below worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work. Works fine for me

```
<?php
    $allFiles = scandir('../php/'); // REPLACE WITH YOUR DIRECTORY


    foreach($allFiles as $file) {
        $pos = strpos($file, 'php'); // REPLACE PHP WITH YOUR EXTENSION
        $newstring = substr_replace($file, '.', $pos, 0);


        rename("../php/$file", "../php/".$newstring);
    }
?>
```

Comment: God bless you! ... I've screwed it big time :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can begin:

```
<?php

   $string = "filejpeg";
   $pos = strpos($string, 'jpeg');

   $newstring = substr_replace($string, '.', $pos, 0);

    var_dump($newstring);
?>
```